# How can I debug a very basic parallel-ssh failure for a trivial example?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I was trying to troubleshoot this myself by reducing the failing example until a more basic solution was working. However, even the simplest use of `parallel-ssh` that I can imagine below fails, and googling hasn't helped me decipher the error message. Does anyone have any ideas what the problem is or how I could debug this further? Here's the output:

```
$ parallel-ssh -H localhost 'echo foo'
[1] 19:20:54 [FAILURE] localhost Exited with error code 255
```

Comment: Are you running an SSH server on localhost. Can you do `ssh localhost 'echo foo'`?

Comment: Oops, I guess not on my local machine... Now I wonder why this isn't working on the other machine, which is running an ssh server. Does parallel-ssh support ipv6? For example `ssh <IPV6>%eth0 'echo foo'` works, but the corresponding `parallel-ssh` fails with the same 255 error code.

Comment: It looks to me like it uses the `ssh` program, so it supports whatever that supports.

Comment: Directly substituting `parallel-ssh -H ` for `ssh` does not work in the case of ipv6 link-local addresses apparently. Must be failing to parse the host for some reason.

Comment: Aha, the actual original problem I'm facing is that `parallel-ssh` in no way shape or form supports ipv6. From the source code of `parse_host`: `if ':' in host:
        host, port = host.rsplit(':', 1)`

Comment: Use hostnames instead of IPv6 addresses.

Comment: Scratch that. The use of `rsplit` lets me just supply the suffix `:22` and it works!

Comment: @Barmar, in my case there is no dns (otherwise, I would not be resorting to IPV6 link local addressing)

Comment: Can you put them in `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: Maybe, but that's not very portable to other systems, and requires maintenance compared to the append `:22` solution I think.

Comment: Hard-coding addresses into a script is better? OK.

Comment: @jonderry IPv6 support appears buggy, though. `2001:db8::1` is a valid IPv6 address that `parse_host` would apparently split into `2001:db8:` and `1`.

Comment: @chepner, exactly, that's why you always append the port.

Comment: Still a bug, just one you can work around :)